# Latin squares generator? (Sudoku-like constraint problem)

Tags: language-agnostic, constraints, sudoku, latin-square

**Purpose**

We're designing a Latin square (sudoku-like sequence) for an experimental design that needs to follow these constraints:

- Values cannot be repeated in a row
- Values cannot be repeated in a column
- Values cannot be repeated pairwise in any two rows

Example for the first 3 constraints:

```
2     3    5    7    11   13
7     2    11   3    13   5
11    5    2    13   7    3
3     7    13   2    5    11
5     13   3    11   2    7
13    11   7    5    3    2
```

Here, we chose primes, but the values are arbitrary (as long as there are 6 distinct values).  Notice that it's the same as sudoku in a 6 x 6 grid, with the additional constraint that there are no repeated pairs (a.k.a. bigrams) across rows.  That is, `2 3` only appears on the first row, but in no others, and so on for every other pair.

- Values should be pair with another 6 values that fit these constraints:

  - The 2nd-set values cannot be repeated in a row
  - The 2nd-set values cannot be repeated in a column
  - When paired with the 1st-set values, the 2nd-set values cannot be repeated.

That is, we need to have another six values (again, arbitrary -- they could be "a, b, c, d, e, f") that pair with the first six.  The last constraint means that if you use (`2`, a) *anywhere*, you cannot use it again.

The last 2nd-set constraint is the problem.  There is no solution for n x n grids where n = 6.  That's the monkey wrench in the works.  We want to minimize the number of repeats, to make a "sorta-kinda" orthogonal pair of Latin squares.

**Question**

Have you encountered this problem before?  (It'd be great if there were a tool that will generate solutions.)  We only need one such example for our purposes.  We've tried several different construction strategies already.

We're flirting with the idea of writing a solver for it, but we'd like to avoid doing so if something already exists.

Comment: homework? if yes, please tag it as such

Comment: You did a good job explaining the first set of 3 constraints, but I have no idea what you mean by the later set of constraints. Also you say it is unsolvable but ask for a solution? Please clarify.

Comment: No, not homework.  I thought someone would say that though.  :)  This is a real problem we ran into at my workplace.

Comment: @Brian: Sorry about the "solution" thing -- part of a sentence was left over from a previous draft of the question.  I've updated the second to last paragraph to reflect this.

Comment: @Brian:  Regarding the constraints:  we need 2 Latin squares.  The first can't have pairs repeated by each row (the first set of constraints).  The second is just a normal Latin square, but it needs to be "sorta-kinda" orthogonal to the first.  (That is, when combined, we would like to repeat (2, a), (3, b), (4, a) etc. as few times as possible.)  We know that no perfect orthogonal solution exists, but we'd like to get as close as we can.

Comment: How quickly do you have to compute your squares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wrote a solver that randomly permuted solutions and took the best balanced solution available after running it overnight.  It might not be the best approach, but since a perfect solution doesn't exist for the constraints, we thought it should be better than other methods of finding a "not-so-bad" solution.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look: [Dancing Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links)

> In computer science, Dancing Links, also known as DLX, is the technique suggested by Donald Knuth to efficiently implement his Algorithm X. Algorithm X is a recursive, nondeterministic, depth-first, backtracking algorithm that finds all solutions to the exact cover problem. Some of the better-known exact cover problems include tiling, the N queens problem, and Sudoku.

Comment: Thanks, we weren't previously aware of this.  I'm not sure how applicable this would be, given that it's more of a minimization problem (at the moment).  We may see if we can change our `n` to 5 or 7.